# javascript inside iframe not working

Tags: javascript, iframe

I use URL's like: http://example.com/videos/GF60Iuh643I
I'm trying to use javascript inside iframe to embed youtube videos:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<script type="text/javascript">
var segment_str = window.location.pathname;
var segment_array = segment_str.split( '/' );
var last_segment = segment_array.pop();
document.write(last_segment); 
</script>" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It should give src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GF60Iuh643I"

But instead the javascript remains unexecuted, 
any idea how to make this work?

Thank you!

Comment: main issue in your code that you can't add js script inside iframe element like this

Answer (score 2):

Try this(not tested). You get the iframe by id and then set the src to equal the link +  the last segment.

```
<iframe id="videoframe" width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"  allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
var segment_str = window.location.pathname;
var segment_array = segment_str.split( '/' );
var last_segment = segment_array.pop();
document.getElementById('videoframe').src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + last_segment;
</script>
```

Comment: Glad, I could help.